# Рисование линий в MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Дан массив точек вида `(x, y)`. Необходимо соединить линией первую точку со второй, третью с четвертой, пятую с шестой и т.д и нарисовать всё это. Как это сделать с помощью функций `MATLAB`?

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
y = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5];
plot(x, y)
```